# Anyone have fruit disease dataset?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, dataset, convolution

I am doing a project on fruit disease recognition and classification. Anyone have an existing dataset of fruit diseases? Can you help me to find one?

Comment: There is another stack for data requests -  https://opendata.stackexchange.com/  give it a try

Comment: @yoav_aaa thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work on plant disease image recognition for my Master's thesis. Until now, I did not find any good database with fruit images, but there are two quite large databases which contain leaf-images of infected plants. One is the [Plantvillage](https://plantvillage.psu.edu)-dataset which has pictures taken under laboratory conditions and the other one is the [Digipathos](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jayme_Barbedo/publication/325824675_Factors_influencing_the_use_of_deep_learning_for_plant_disease_recognition/links/5b27c206458515af5ca1235f/Factors-influencing-the-use-of-deep-learning-for-plant-disease-recognition.pdf)-dataset which contains pictures that are nearer to real-life scenarios with multiple objects in focus and difficult backgrounds.

You can download the Plantvillage-dataset from this [Github-Repo](https://github.com/spMohanty/PlantVillage-Dataset). For the Digipathos-dataset, I wrote a downloader which you can also find [on Github](https://github.com/georg-un/digipathos-plant-disease-img-db-downloader).

Comment: Does have PlantVillage fruits or vegetables image dataset? As far as I know, Plant Villages also does not provide their datasets anymore, does it?

Comment: The PlantVillage dataset contains only images of plant leaves. The Digipathos dataset has few images with fruits but not enough to train a CNN on them. From the PlantVillage dataset, 50.000 images are still available for download. You can download them from the [Github Repo](https://github.com/spMohanty/PlantVillage-Dataset) of one of the researchers.